# WebSocket connection timed out AWS EC2 + Ratchet PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, javascript

I have a problem involving WebSockets, well, I have a website, and recently I put SSL on it, using Let's Encrypt, okay, SSL works perfectly, along with my website that is hosted on EC2, with a domain that I bought on Route 53, however, I am facing a problem when trying to establish a connection with WebSockets, I have a chat that uses the PHP Ratchet library, and by default I used port 8080 to establish a connection between server and client, however, as I am using SSL, port 8080 it will not take effect, that said, I tried to use several ports, 8443, 8080, 3000, 8181, 8282, 4433, and none of them really work, because the Google console reports failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out error. Well, I don't really know if the problem is with the server or the client, I think it is with the client, since the php script runs perfectly, but does not accept connections. I've also enabled all these ports that I mentioned, in the security group of my EC2 machine, but the error persists, well, is this a problem involving Let's Encrypt? Should I edit an SSL file to establish connections via WebSocket? Or should I edit httpd.conf? I really don't know what to do, I believe everything is fine with my code, however, nothing works
Incidentally, now when I try to use port 8443, the PHP script says that the port is already in use, and I've already tried to stop this process that is running, using the command *fuser -k 8443/tcp*, but the process doesn't stop, well, the only alternative port to use with SSL is 8443? Is there any other door? If not, how do I stop the process in which the door is running
I really need help, I'm a beginner and for me this becomes something very complex, because I always try a new thing and it always goes wrong

**JS:**

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://example.com:4433/welcome.php'); //Using port 4433, it doesn't works as any port, I already tried a lot of ports
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Anne\Socket\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
         ),
        4433
    );

    $server->run();
```

***Google Console:***

> WebSocket connection to "mysite" failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

**AWS Security Groups:**

```
Ports   Protocol    Source  SecurityGroup
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
8080    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
4433    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
8443    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
3000    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
```

Comment: Should I create a new EC2 instance?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall instance. Your security groups look good, but check if you have an additional firewall on your instance.

Comment: Welcome Anne. A tip, if you break up your question into sentences and paragraphs it's easier for people to read, and you'll get more help. A new EC2 instance probably won't help, you need to look at security groups, NACLs, instance firewalls, maybe routing.